# catkin_package() CATKIN_DEPENDS on 'console_bridge' but it is not a catkin package

Tags: ros, catkin, homebrew, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Homebrew installation is still experimental, and perhaps that's what I'm running into here.  But I just wanted to bring a little attention to this problem I'm encountering.

Specifically, when I try to do the isolated install (i.e. ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install) I end up seeing the following error:

> CMake Error at
> /Users/Yeison/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:173
> (message):
> catkin_package() CATKIN_DEPENDS on 'console_bridge',
> which has been found   in
> '/Users/Yeison/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/console_bridge/cmake/console_bridge-config.cmake',
> but it is not a catkin package
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /Users/Yeison/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98
> (_catkin_package)   CMakeLists.txt:11
> (catkin_package)

Full output:
https://gist.github.com/yeison/5244376

Also a related question:
http://answers.ros.org/question/50191/groovy-beta-1-having-trouble-installing-console_bridge-required-by-vision_opencv/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59206/catkin_package()-catkin_depends-on-%27console_bridge%27-but-it-is-not-a-catkin-package/) by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I completely removed the src directory from my workspace and pulled down a brand new working copy:

```
wstool init -j8 src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
```

It seems to have addressed the problem I was having.  I'm not sure what could have been the cause of it.

---

Originally posted by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) with karma: 103 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0